# nginx add ssl the interface concurrent test took 10 times longer than http

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

windows nginx config
http config

```
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$upstream_response_time $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    gzip on; 
    gzip_static on; 
    gzip_disable "msie6"; 
    gzip_min_length 100k;  
    gzip_buffers 4 16k;  
    gzip_comp_level 5;  
    gzip_types text/plain application/json application/x-javascript text/css application/xml text/javascript application/x-httpd-php image/jpeg image/gif image/png;  
    gzip_vary off;
```

server config

```
        listen 443 ssl http2; 
        server_name www.xxxxxxx.com;
        ssl_certificate C://com.cer; 
        ssl_certificate_key C://server.key; 
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; 
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL:!DH:!EDH:!AESGCM:!kEDH;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        keepalive_timeout   10;
```

Concurrent test the http request's avg time/min time/max time less then https request's 10 times

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry i used jmeter like this and i found test 1 time,jmeter's result was longer then chrome,so i change it use apache bench tool,it test result close to jmeter test http request result